# Error saying I have NA/NaN/Inf value when there seems to be none present. Error in hclustfun(distc) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)

Tags: r, nan, na, gplots

I have a file that looks like this :

```
Taxa,D0,D1,...
1,0,10,...
20,0,0,...
...
```

The file is available here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvtxztz3kypnxre/Taxa_Conf.csv?dl=0

When I run a script by

```
$CONCOCT/scripts/ConfPlot.R -c Taxa_Conf.csv -o Taxa_Conf.pdf
```

I get the following error :

```
Error in hclustfun(distc) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)
Calls: heatmap.2 -> hclustfun
Execution halted
```

where ConfPlot.R looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

#load libraries
library(gplots)
library(getopt)

spec = matrix(c('verbose','v',0,"logical",'help','h',0,"logical",'confile','c',1,"character",'ofile','o',1,"character"),byrow=TRUE,ncol=4)

opt=getopt(spec)

if( !is.null(opt$help)) {
cat(getopt(spec, usage=TRUE)); 
q(status=1);
}

confFile <- opt$confile

Conf <- read.csv(confFile,header=TRUE,row.names=1)
Conf.t <- t(Conf)
ConfP <- Conf.t/rowSums(Conf.t)

crp <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","red","orange","yellow"))(100)

pdf(opt$ofile)

heatmap.2 (as.matrix(t(ConfP)),col=crp,trace="none",dendrogram="none",Rowv=FALSE,lwid = c(1.25,4.5),lhei = c(1.25,4.5),cexRow=0.5)

dev.off()
```

After reading [Error while creating heatmaps - NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738900/error-while-creating-heatmaps-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-11/39087088), I tried

```
> a=read.csv("/home/mathed/Simulation/custom_desman/1/Strains/Simulation/Metabat/Taxa_Conf.csv",header=TRUE,row.names=1)
> any(is.na(a))
[1] FALSE
```

There seems to be no NA value.
ConfPlot.R works for my other files.
What is the problem?? There does not seem to be any na, nan, or inf value.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this row:

```
ConfP <- Conf.t/rowSums(Conf.t)
```

It must be evaluating essentially to division by zero:

```
> 0/0
[1] NaN

> 1/0
[1] Inf
```

Comment: Oh! I now see why it results in NaN! Thank you very much @zx8754

Comment: It seems that the first column D0 with all zeros is the problem! Thank you very much.